# Script an SQL server remote data import with SQL authentication

Tags: sql, sql-server, import, ssms

While SSMS will generate scripts to create tables and data, I was unable to find references to the possibility of scripting a data import, one that would go to a remote server using SQL authentication. Did I miss the option in the wizard?

My questions is whether it's possible to script a remote data import using SQL server. The end goal is to keep two databases synchronized at regularly scheduled intervals, while specifying which tables to synchronize.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I believe that replication would help you here. Why not use that?

Comment: Some other things you could consider are linked servers or SSIS packages

Answer (score 0):

**Replication** is the way to go in this case. You can Select Articles(Sql Server Objects) that you want to copy/replicated over to your Remote server or copy/replicated to your local server from your remote server. 
To set the **Level Of synchronize**  between Publisher and Subscriber you have three option. You are better off reading a bit more about it urself and see which suits your needs best. 
This Link is a good read have a look. [Replication Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/215093/Replication-in-MS-SQL-Server)

Comment: Just to add information to readers. Replication feature is not available on SQL Server Express Edition. So if you are using two databases on same server, you can think of writing triggers which is a pain at a cost of saving money for SQL Server Standard edition.

Comment: @ShantanuGupta this is probably suitable for you, but Companies with even very small budget will be using at least `Standard Edition` in which replication is available. If a business is using Express Edition and they cant afford to upgrade to at least standard edition then Sql server isnt the right choice for them.

Comment: Totally agree. I added comments for developers sitting at home learning or exploring technology features :) (Applicable in my case)

Comment: Developers should use SQL Server Developer's Edition which has all the feature of Enterprise Edition. After all you have to have hands on with all the features of Sql Server if you really want to learn, I think it only costs around £50-£60. Well worth it though :)